Context-Free Grammer in Chomsky's Normal Form to Pushdown Automaton
I am currently studying formal languages and automata and have encountered a challenge in converting a context-free grammar (CFG) that's in Chomsky Normal Form (CNF) into a corresponding Pushdown Automaton (PDA). I understand the general approach to constructing PDAs from CFGs but am having difficulty applying these concepts to grammars with recursive productions and multiple production rules per non-terminal.
Here is the CFG I am working with:
S→ AB ∣ SA ∣ SB
A→ BS ∣ a
B→ AS ∣ b
Each rule adheres to the CNF requirements, where productions are either of the form
A→BC or A→a, with A,B, and C being non-terminal symbols and a being a terminal symbol. Here's my specific question:
Initialization: How should I initiate the stack of the PDA? I assume I start with pushing the start symbol S, but how should the state transitions be managed effectively considering there are recursive rules like S→SA?
Transitions for Recursive Productions: Given the recursive nature of some rules, e.g.,S→SA, how do I design the transitions so the PDA doesn't get stuck in a loop or fail to process the input correctly?
Handling Terminal Symbols: For productions that lead directly to terminals (like A→a), what's the best practice for designing transitions that read these terminals and manage the stack simultaneously?
Final Acceptance State: Should the PDA only accept by empty stack, or is there a need for a specific final state once all input is processed?
A reference of the final PDA would be massively appriciated. I'm particularly interested in practical strategies for mapping these CFG rules to a PDA's transitions and states, including any specific considerations for ensuring the automaton accurately processes strings according to the CFG.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
